# Will the row sumation of $({{\bf B}^T{\bf B}})^{-1}$ nonnegative? Column vectors of ${\bf B}$ are independent and normalized

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If column vectors of ${\bf B}$ are independent and normalized, can we conclude the row summation of $({{\bf B}^T{\bf B}})^{-1}$ nonnegative? By row summation, I　mean $({{\bf B}^T{\bf B}})^{-1}{\bf 1}$. ${\bf 1}$ is a vector with components all one's.

Sorry for this question. Seems what I need is only ${\bf 1}^T({\bf B}^T{\bf B}){\bf 1}>0$. But this is trivial.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: What is the row summation?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I'd think it is the sum of the entries in a row?

Comment: What's the background, motivation for this question?

Answer (score 1):

No.

This is rather crude, but let
$$ B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0.85 & 0.52669 \\
0 & 0.52678 & -0.83086 \\
0 & 0 & 0.17963 \end{array} \right).$$
We have $||B e_i|| = 1$, so the columns are normalized,
the eigenvalues of $B^T B$ are $0.05, 0.99, 2.00$, so the columns of $B$ are independent, but
$$(B^T B)^{-1} \left( \begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
1 \end{array} \right)=
\left( \begin{array}{c}
-40.544 \\
35.243 \\
22.002 \end{array} \right)
.$$

Comment: But my question is if the components of $({\bf B}^T{\bf B})^{-1}{\bf 1}$ are all nonnegative. For the example you give, $({\bf B}^T{\bf B})^{-1}{\bf 1}=(120.0004 85.0006 84.9999)^T$. All of the components are positive.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that!

Comment: @mining: I fixed by example, I think it satisfies all the conditions, but the row sum in negative.